# Tableau How to evenly split a Ranking Table into two

Tags: tableau-api, rank

I am trying to evenly split a ranking table into two.

I tried to create a calculated field using rank to divide the data into two groups.
[image]
[image]

The problem with this approach is that there are too many entries in the first column because they are tie with rank 1.

[image]

I don't want to break the tie but display evenly in both columns.

So, desired output will look like...

25 states with Rank 1 are displayed in column 1, and the rest 12 rank 1 states and the other states from rank 38 to 49 are displayed in column 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to split your rows within a specif number (say 25) you can't rely just on rank due to same values for multiple rows.

Even though your Rank calculated field must be shown in the chart, you can add another calculated field based on rank_unique which will provide you a progressive number for rows having the same value for the specified metric.

[image]

Just use the specified function:

```
RANK_UNIQUE(SUM([Value]),'desc')
```

And then use the calculated field as a filter to "split" the results as you need (in this example 1-4, 5-8).

[image]

Comment: Would using Index() work here rather than having to bake a custom ranking function?

Comment: index would work as well... rank_unique is just more rank-relatable ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try this way and let you know! 

BTW, when I used Index(), it gave me the index along the state name not the number (Profit in my case)

Comment: It did it lol Thank you.

Comment: I've just realised that I left index in the screenshot... hopefully it won't be misleading... for your need you could use either rank_unique and index